# What is the purpose of setDoInput and setDoOutput in Java HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java

What is the function or purpose of `HttpURLConnection.setDoInput` and `HttpURLConnection.setDoOutput`?

Answer (score 31):

From the documentation for [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html):

> Set the DoInput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for input, false if not. The default is true.
>
> Set the DoOutput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for output, false if not. The default is false.

As for the actual purpose, it doesn't appear that anything in the Oracle code checks on the `doInput` variable. However the `doOutput` default of false will prevent you from calling `getOutputStream()` necessary for HTTP POST requests. So it is a way to indicate ahead of time that you expect to write to an `OutputStream` without actually establishing it.

Comment: Yes I read the documentation.  Just don't understand by "intend to use the URL connection for input when true and false if not".  What really does it mean ?

Comment: I just added a bit more to the answer from what I know.

Comment: setDoInput(false) is called when the response body is going to be ignored. The Java core code does call this for JAXB and XML serialization to URLs. See: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serialize/DOMSerializerImpl.java and javax\xml\bind\JAXB.java

Comment: Note that if you setDoInput(false) then you can't even check for success with getResponseCode(), since that implicitly opens the inputstream.

Comment: The documentation on setDoInput sucks. I was surprised to find that "intended to do input" means to read from the connection,  not to actually put stuff into it (because that's what "doing input" means).

Answer (score 19):

I was still confused as to what exactly was meant in the documentation by "Use the url connection for input".

That could mean that you want read information from the response or that you want to input information into its request.
The documentation states:

> A URL connection can be used for input and/or output. Setting the doInput flag to true
> indicates that the application intends to read data from the URL connection.
>
> The default value of this field is true.

So if you want to ignore data from the response then you can set doInput to false.
If you want to use getInputStream() then you should leave this alone or set it to true.

> A URL connection can be used for input and/or output. Setting the doOutput flag to true
> indicates that the application intends to write data to the URL connection.
>
> The default value of this field is false.

So if you want append data to the request (calling getOutputStream()) then you must set doOutput to true.

Comment: input means you want to send a POST or PUT request

Answer (score 0):

The methods are declared by the superclass, `URLConnection`. I think the intention was to enable potential optimizations in the concrete implementations. Remember that `URLConnection` is protocol agnostic (but `HttpURLConnection` is obviously not).

Comment: `protocol agnostic`? what do you mean?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub Not tied to any specific protocol, like HTTP or FTP.