# Java: What is the purpose of setDoInput in URLConnection

Tags: java, http-post, urlconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583064/java-httpurlconnection)

Would this method be used for example if I want to read the response to a POST method call from the server I am connected to?

Comment: `setDoInput(false)` = Ignores the response body, and disallows use of `getResponseCode()` also.

Comment: That's incorrect. setDoInput(false) just means you aren't interested in a response body, you still get the headers, and you can still call getResponseCode().  setDoInput(false) might be valid for a REST API where you expect a 204 response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never encountered a case for setting it false. You always want to read something, at least the response code.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to "ping" a server without requesting any results (not even the return codes) or anything